# ChromeDriver and Chrome.exe doesnt close sometimes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing problems with the chrome processes not closing after tests are done.

If i debug each testcase **and** also debug them by changing the test so the tests fail on purpose, the TearDown method is being always called and all processes are killed.

But sometimes and this happens in like 1 of 10 runs, some processes stay alive when not run in debug.

I found this issue report from 2018:
[Chromedriver quit() method doesn't close all chrome.exe processes GITHUB](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6317)
in which some people are facing the same issue.

In this link, there is not a fix mentioned.

Someone is mentioning in that link above that the reason could be caused by "Zombie processes" explained here:
[Zombie Processes are Eating your Memory](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/zombie-processes-are-eating-your-memory/)

Did anyone else face such issues?

Comment: Missing basic debugging details

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because the tear down function as you mentioned is not called
first how do you call your tear down function ?

Comment: As i know, the tear down is called automtically after a [Test] is pass or fail. I created a call of the teardown method at the end of a [Test] method, but when the test fails, it automatically jumps to the teardown and never gets to the code i added to call the teardown method. So i deleted it again.

Comment: Try to modify the tear down function ->  if ( driver != null ) driver.close() ; driver = null ;      With this the tear down function will check if the driver is null or not and close it every time